# Set array value into structure in golang

Tags: go

The structure is

```
type TopicModels struct {
    Topics []string
}
```

And I want to set the value into this structure like following approach

```
var topics [2]string
topics[0] = "Sport Nice"
topics[1] = "Nice Sport"
return &TopicModels{Topics: topics}, nil
```

However, it tells me that

```
 cannot use topics (type [2]string) as type []string in field value
```

How can I change the code to make it correct?

Comment: See the language specification the Slice blog entry and the Go Tour to understand the difference between slices and arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, the `Topics` field has type `[]string` (an arbitrary length slice of strings), and the `topics` variable has type `[2]string` (an string array of length 2).  These are not the same type, so you get the error.

There are two ways you could go about solving this:

1. make `topics` a slice:

   ```
   topics = make([]string, 2)
   topics[0] = "Sport Nice"
   ...
   ```
2. Use a [slice expression](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) to create a slice representing your array:

   ```
   ...
   return &TopicModels{Topics: topics[:]}, nil
   ```

Comment: I think you need to use `make`, not `new`.

Comment: Thanks.  I've made the fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an `array literal` by doing this...

```
topics := [2]string{"Sport Nice","Nice Sport"}
return &TopicModels{Topics: topics}, nil
```

Here is a nice blog entry about array's and slices... http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

EDIT

forgot to mention you need to change the struct

```
type TopicModels struct {
    Topics [2]string
}
```

Comment: Neither of those will work, because `TopicModels.Topics` expects a slice rather than an array.

Comment: Yeh i forgot to mention to change the struct... Thanks @JamesHenstridge